# html form elements and using php to get data

Tags: php, html, email

I have searched and found some good potential solutions, but can't seem to make this work.  I'm still a beginner.  I'm using form elements with dropdowns, and attempting to get the user input and then send the information via email.  I will post the html and php here:

```
            <form method = "post">
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="dropdown">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary-outline dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" name="size">Choose Size&nbsp;
                  <span class="caret"></span></button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>14 x 20</li>
                    <li>16 x 26</li>
                    <li>18 x 30</li>
                    <li>20 x 32</li>
                    <li>22 x 38</li>
                    <li>28 x 44</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </fieldset>


            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-primary-outline dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" name="color">Choose Color
              <span class="caret"></span></button>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>Blue</li>
                    <li>Lt Blue</li>
                    <li>Purple</li>
                    <li>Lavendar</li>
                    <li>Green</li>
                    <li>Lt Green</li>
                    <li>Black</li>
                    <li>Pink</li>

                </ul>
            </div>
```

and the PHP:

```
<?php

$error = ""; $successMessage = "";

if (isset($_POST['size'])) {
    $size = $_POST['size'];
    $size_string = "";
    for($i=0;$i<count($size);$i++) {

        if($i!=0) {

            $size_string = $size_string . ", ";

        }

        $size_string = $size_string . $service[$i];

    }

} else {

    $error .= "Please select a size from the dropdown menu.<br>";

}

    if (isset($_POST['color'])) {

        $color = $_POST['color'];
        $color_string = "";
        for($i=0;$i<count($color);$i++) {

            if($i!=0)  {

                $color_string = $color_string . ", ";

            }

            $color_string = $color_string . $color[$i];

        }

    } else {

        $error .= "Please select a color from the dropdown menu.<br>";

    }

...

$emailTo = "me@mydomain.com";

$subject = "Mat Order";

$content = $_POST['color'];
$content .= $_POST['size'];
$content .= $_POST['monogram']
```

Sorry for the large amount of code, just trying to paste the pertinent areas.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: mail($emailTo,$subject,$content); http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: *Hey there Pops!* You've any mail code?  if not, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php or better yet, phpmailer https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer - *Scooby doobie wah wah wah ♫*

Comment: Thanks Fred!  Giving it another go now :)

Comment: You're welcome *Pops!* - Btw... you can ping someone directly by using the `@` symbol followed by their name ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: @PopsJones and seeing that `<form method = "post">` and not `action`, means that it is to execute on the same page. If you're using separate files, then you'll need to use the action syntax for it. I.e.: `<form method = "post" action="handler.php">`.

Comment: Are you doing some pre-processing in jQuery or JavaScript before submitting your form? Reason I ask is because if you post your form as is it won't post the value of your `<li>` since it's not an `<input />`.

Comment: @RatHat I was not pre-processing.  I appreciate the advice on the <input>  and will take a look.  Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks again, gonna take a look at this, since it may be of value to separate the files and use 'action'.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: *You're welcome* @PopsJones

Comment: As @RatHat said, you are not using form controls, you are using layers that bootstrap stylize to seem what it doesn't is. So the values will not send. Use `<select>` tag and if you want to stylize use plugins such as [select2](https://select2.github.io/) or [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). Good luck.

Comment: Thank you @MarcosPérezGude, I appreciate the response!  I am looking into using <select> as well as other suggestions.  I have gotten terrific advice today!

Comment: You are welcome. We are learning everyday :)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the plugins mentioned above, below is a snippet of jQuery code that will pre-process and submit the form. Also as mentioned in the comments above make sure to add and "action" to your form and a submit button.

```
<form method="post" action="pathToYourphp.php">
    <!-- Your form content here -->
    <button id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

jQuery code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // This will replace the text in the dropdown with the item selected from the list
    $(".dropdown-menu li").click(function(){
        $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.dropdown-toggle').html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
        $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.dropdown-toggle').val($(this).data('value'));
    });
    // Handle the submit button click
    $('#submitBtn').click(function(event) {
        // prevent the form from submitting
        event.preventDefault();
        // Get the form to submit
        var form = $(this).closest('form');
        // Add hidden inputs dynamically to the form
        // and fill them with the correct value
        // This will grab the "name" attribute from
        // your button
        $('.dropdown-toggle').each(function() {
            var input = $("<input>")
           .attr("type", "hidden")
           .attr("name", $(this).attr("name"))
           .val($(this).text().trim());
            form.append($(input));
        });
        //submit the form
        form.submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

You should have jQuery available since you are using bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you @RatHat this is extremely helpful!  I am furiously reviewing jQuery notes now.  This makes great sense.

Comment: I'm still struggling with the PHP portion of this.  I'm attempting to send the pre-processed input data to an email (to myself).  I'm sure I've missed a bit of `code` $size = $_POST['size'];
  $color = $_POST['color'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
        
        $emailTo = "me@mydomain.com";
        $subject = "Mat Order";
        $content = "Size $size Color $color <br>$message";

Comment: Did you add a "message" input or textarea to your form? Basically the $_POST superglobal checks the request send by the client for key value pairs where the key is the name of your input and value is its value. Say you have a text box `<input type="text" name="message" value="Hey php" />` when you post this form to php, the value of $_POST["message"] is going to be "Hey php", so "message" is the key and "Hey php" is the value. If you don't have an input with name="message" then $message in php is empty. To test if php is sending emails this tool is super handy https://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/

Comment: thanks for the tool link.  I appreciate all the great info, my plan is to never finish learning :)